# How can the approvers assigned to an approval process approve it?

Tags: permissions, approval-process

As a system admin, I've sent an email to the assigned approvers (automated) so that they can approve the process. Within the email, I've also attached the external URL link for the approval request as shown below. But when the approver click on this url, it says that you don't have access to the record (as shown below). But I've given the necessary access to the user to approve it. What should I do now so that approver can approve the request?

Thanks in advance :)

[image: Email content]

[image: This opens up when the approver click on the link]

Answer (score 0):

As per the error what I think is that, the one who is the approver, his/her profile does not have the correct license. Once try giving the approver the System Admin license and see if it works. If it does then positively you need to look into the licenses else the problem is somewhere else. Hope my suggestion was useful.